# How to deploy the Blazor web application on the web? What is the step by step procedure?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to the web application development. I have developed a Blazor web application (Server-sdie) on Visual studio by reading many blogs and watching tutorials on YouTube. Eventually I have learnt how to code it. I have got the expected results while debugging/running on Chrome - locathost.

Now, I want to buy a domain and make my web application live on the internet. I don't know how to do it. Helping hands will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have some server space for your application. I suggest creating a free Azure account. You can easily publish your application on Azure (few clicks from VisualStudio), you will be assigned an address on Azure and you will be able to check the application in action.
Many Azure services are free - maybe that's enough to get you started?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm looking to buy a domain and make my app live on the internet. Please guide me the steps if you can.

Comment: Here is an example page with step-by-step instructions on how to publish it: [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-blazor-application-on-azure-cf6f3b1f03a0/). 
Of course, you can skip creating the database in Azure and skip to "Publishing...".